# Extract ints from bytes in iOS

Tags: ios, nsdata

I’m trying to construct a CMap from “FontFile2” in a PDF.

I have bytes that I know are BigEndian stored in an NSData object. 
I’d like to read the first 4 bytes as raw data.
Then  I’d like to read the following 8 bytes as 4 unsigned shorts.

Then I’d like to read the following 16 bytes as a 4 byte string followed by three unsigned longs. 
Then maybe a few more 4 byte strings followed by three unsigned longs.

*edit*

```
  NSData* subdata = [stream subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];
    const unsigned char *bytes = [subdata bytes];
    int test = *(int*)bytes;
```

My failed attempt at reading the first 4 bytes as a short. 
It seems that breaking up the data into a bunch of subdata objects is overly complex. Their must be an easier way...

Thanks

Comment: Post relevant code showing the data you have and the attempt you have made to extract the values you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if you want to read bytes, you should create an `NSInteger` to store the position of read bytes.

For example, this is how you read `short`:

```
@property NSInteger position;

NSData *yourData;

short extractedShort;
[yourData getBytes:&temp range:NSMakeRange(self.position, sizeof(extractedShort))];
self.position += sizeof(extractedShort);
```

Read `int`, `NSString`, `float`, `long` ... value are similar